# get the total online time between 2 dates

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following collection:

```
[
  { "_id" : ObjectId("5e7b38534512e95591e14c59"), "name" : "Luna", "online" : true },
  { "_id" : ObjectId("5e7b386b4512e95591e14c5a"), "name" : "Luna", "online" : false },
  { "_id" : ObjectId("5e7b386b4512e95591e14c5b"), "name" : "Luna", "online" : true },
  { "_id" : ObjectId("5e7b4e128e6bf5694924db09"), "name" : "Luna", "online" : false },
  { "_id" : ObjectId("5e7b4ec81b36e86a1fb754bf"), "name" : "Luna", "online" : true },
  { "_id" : ObjectId("5e7b4f3b1b36e86a1fb754c0"), "name" : "Luna", "online" : false },
  { "_id" : ObjectId("5e7b4f581b36e86a1fb754c1"), "name" : "Luna", "online" : true },
  { "_id" : ObjectId("5e7b5065f5700f6bee612040"), "name" : "Luna", "online" : false },
  { "_id" : ObjectId("5e7b51a3f5700f6bee612041"), "name" : "Luna", "online" : true },
  { "_id" : ObjectId("5e7b5885f5700f6bee612042"), "name" : "Luna", "online" : false },
  { "_id" : ObjectId("5e7b588ff5700f6bee612043"), "name" : "Luna", "online" : true }
]
```

Now the query I want to have is one that matched data between 2 dates and that counts up the total time online, between those dates. Using mongoId for the timestamp.

Now I have already found how to query data between 2 dates:

```
var objectIdFromDate = function (date) {
    if(typeof date === 'string') date = new Date(date);
    return ObjectId( Math.floor(date.getTime() / 1000).toString(16) + "0000000000000000" );
};

db.getCollection('timeline').aggregate([
    {$match:{
        name:"Luna",
        _id:{
               $gte: objectIdFromDate("2020-03-25T10:54:35.000Z"),
               $lt: objectIdFromDate("2020-03-25T12:36:53.000Z") 
            }
    }},
    // ... ??? ...
])
```

The thing I can't figure out is how I can count up the total time online between the online state (true=login, false=logout)
The document I'd like to receive would look sort of like this:

```
{
  name:"Luna",
  totalTimeOnline:<datetime here>
}
```

Comment: Where are the times? This does not help _anyone_: `ObjectId("5e7b38534512e95591e14c59")` Also, is the data _always_ true-false-true-false... or can you have true-true or false-false?

Comment: there is a timestamp stored in the mongoId, I'm using that one. No the boolean would always toggle... Although when you query between dates it's not always so that the first value of the boolean in the document array would be true. It can start with false, true, false in which case the first true value should be the startdate from the query, same counts if the data ends with a true value then the use the enddate of the query.

Comment: Is TRUE to FALSE the time online and FALSE to TRUE the time spent being offline?

Comment: That is correct @Mr.Polywhirl

Answer (score 0):

You can group the durations by online/offline and reduce the values to get a total count.

The resulting times are displayed has HH:MM:SS and the durations are in milliseconds.

If you noticed, my time intervals are based on the Fibonacci Sequence, with the exception of 01:00 and 01:30, because I needed to make these distinct.

When the current login is ONLINE, the user has been OFFLINE since then.

```js
const main = () => {
  let sessions = calculateSessions(logins);

  Object.keys(sessions).forEach((key) => {
    let duration = sessions[key].reduce((sum, ms) => sum + ms);
    console.log(`Time spent ${key}: ${formatTime(duration)}`);
  });
}

let logins = [
 { "id" :  1, "timestamp" : "2020-03-23T00:00:00.000Z", "online" : true  },
 { "id" :  2, "timestamp" : "2020-03-23T01:00:00.000Z", "online" : false },
 { "id" :  3, "timestamp" : "2020-03-23T01:30:00.000Z", "online" : true  },
 { "id" :  4, "timestamp" : "2020-03-23T02:00:00.000Z", "online" : false },
 { "id" :  5, "timestamp" : "2020-03-23T03:00:00.000Z", "online" : true  },
 { "id" :  6, "timestamp" : "2020-03-23T05:00:00.000Z", "online" : false },
 { "id" :  7, "timestamp" : "2020-03-23T08:00:00.000Z", "online" : true  },
 { "id" :  9, "timestamp" : "2020-03-23T13:00:00.000Z", "online" : false },
 { "id" : 10, "timestamp" : "2020-03-23T21:00:00.000Z", "online" : true  },
 { "id" : 12, "timestamp" : "2020-03-24T10:00:00.000Z", "online" : false },
 { "id" : 13, "timestamp" : "2020-03-25T07:00:00.000Z", "online" : true  }
];

// Assuming dates are pre-sorted and the online status is always staggered
const calculateSessions = (logins) => {
  return logins.reduce((sessions, login, index, all) => {
    if (index > 0) {
      let duration = new Date(login.timestamp) - new Date(all[index - 1].timestamp);
      sessions[login.online ? 'offline' : 'online'].push(duration);
    }
    return sessions;
  }, { online : [], offline : [] });
};

const formatTime = (ms) => {
  const pad = (n, z = 2) => ('00' + n).slice(-z);
  const hh = pad(ms / 3.6e6 | 0);
  const mm = pad((ms % 3.6e6) / 6e4 | 0);
  const ss = pad((ms % 6e4) / 1000 | 0);
  const mmm = pad(ms % 1000, 3);
  return `${hh}:${mm}:${ss}.${mmm}`;
};

main();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

---

Specific use-case

```js
const main = () => {
  let details = calculateTimeOnline('Luna', logins);

  console.log(Object.assign({}, details, {
    totalTimeOnline : formatTime(details.totalTimeOnline)
  }));
}

let logins = [
 { "id" :  1, "timestamp" : "2020-03-23T00:00:00.000Z", "online" : true  },
 { "id" :  2, "timestamp" : "2020-03-23T01:00:00.000Z", "online" : false },
 { "id" :  3, "timestamp" : "2020-03-23T01:30:00.000Z", "online" : true  },
 { "id" :  4, "timestamp" : "2020-03-23T02:00:00.000Z", "online" : false },
 { "id" :  5, "timestamp" : "2020-03-23T03:00:00.000Z", "online" : true  },
 { "id" :  6, "timestamp" : "2020-03-23T05:00:00.000Z", "online" : false },
 { "id" :  7, "timestamp" : "2020-03-23T08:00:00.000Z", "online" : true  },
 { "id" :  9, "timestamp" : "2020-03-23T13:00:00.000Z", "online" : false },
 { "id" : 10, "timestamp" : "2020-03-23T21:00:00.000Z", "online" : true  },
 { "id" : 12, "timestamp" : "2020-03-24T10:00:00.000Z", "online" : false },
 { "id" : 13, "timestamp" : "2020-03-25T07:00:00.000Z", "online" : true  }
];

// Assuming dates are pre-sorted and the online status is always staggered
const calculateTimeOnline = (user, logins) => {
  return logins.reduce((result, login, index, all) => {
    return index > 0 && !login.online
      ? Object.assign(result, {
          totalTimeOnline : result.totalTimeOnline +
            new Date(login.timestamp).getTime() -
            new Date(all[index - 1].timestamp).getTime()
        })
      : result;
  }, {
    name: user,
    totalTimeOnline: 0
  });
};

const formatTime = (ms) => {
  const pad = (n, z = 2) => ('00' + n).slice(-z);
  const hh = pad(ms / 3.6e6 | 0);
  const mm = pad((ms % 3.6e6) / 6e4 | 0);
  const ss = pad((ms % 6e4) / 1000 | 0);
  const mmm = pad(ms % 1000, 3);
  return `${hh}:${mm}:${ss}.${mmm}`;
};

main();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: isn't this possible in mongo aggregate??